# BeautifulSoup : Name error when parsing through Table

Tags: python, html

I am new to scraping. I am trying to scrape a form with tables. I am able to scrape the whole parent tag with beautiful soup. But I am not sure how to traverse through the children tag and get the text inside them.

here is my code

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(htmltext, "html.parser")
tables = soup.find('td',attrs={'class':'title_heading'})
for table in tables:
    print(table)
    form_name = table.td.center.strong.u.text *--ERROR---*
```

The above code prints the everything inside the `<td>` tag. The error occurs when i try to traverse through the children tag.

```
File "E:\Study_naveen\python\scrape.py", line 23, in <module>
form_name = table.td.center.strong.u.text
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'center'
```

Here is my html

```
<td width="615" class="title_heading"><center>
<strong><u> ONLINE REGISTRATION FORM</u></strong>
<br><br>
<strong>Blah<br>
123456789-<br>
blah blah<br>
phone - 123456789
999999999<br>
Email : something@gmail.com.</strong>
```

I want to get the "Online resgistration form" text inside . How do i go about this ?

Answer (score 0):

```
html = '''<td width="615" class="title_heading"><center>
<strong><u> ONLINE REGISTRATION FORM</u></strong>
<br><br>
<strong>Blah<br>
123456789-<br>
blah blah<br>
phone - 123456789
999999999<br>
Email : something@gmail.com.</strong>'''
import bs4

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
text = soup.find('td', class_="title_heading").find('strong').text
print(text)
```

out:

```
 ONLINE REGISTRATION FORM
```